# TLS/PSK key length

Tags: ssl

Is there a maximum length for the length of the key. I am using gnutls's psktool to create keys and I need to create key of the size of 128 bits. but the maximum value it lets me to use as key length is 64 Is this impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnutls's psktool takes the key size in bytes, not in bits. So the maximum length is 64 bytes = 512 bits.